# VHDL code : statement in the If condition not getting updated

Tags: vhdl

I'm new to VHDL language. I'm trying to code a universal shift register using 4:1 mux and D flip flop. when the select line of the 4:1 mux is "01" I do shift right operation. I wrote all the statement that must execute when this condition satisfies.

I'm using instances of 4:1 mux in my code.Individually when tested each mux, output is coming correctly .But when put inside the if statement of universal shift register the output of mux still says undefined when simulated.

Can anyone help me??

Below is my code

```
entity universal_sft_reg is  
    Port ( serial_in_left_ip : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           serial_in_rt_ip : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           parallel_ip : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);  
           parallel_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (7 downto 0);  
              serial_out : out  STD_LOGIC;  
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           sel : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (1 downto 0));  
end universal_sft_reg;

architecture Behavioral of universal_sft_reg is  
component four_one_mux is  
    Port ( in0 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in1 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           in2 : in  STD_LOGIC;
           in3 : in  STD_LOGIC;  
              s0 : in STD_LOGIC;  
              s1 : in STD_LOGIC;  
           y : out  STD_LOGIC);  
end component;

component DFF is  
    Port ( d : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           q : out  STD_LOGIC;  
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;  
           clk : in  STD_LOGIC);  
end component;  

signal d1,d2,d3,d4,d5,d6,d7,d8 : STD_LOGIC;  
signal y1,y2,y3,y4,y5,y6,y7,y8 : STD_LOGIC;                                                                  signal n0_1,in1_1,in2_1,in3_1,in0_2,in1_2,in2_2,in3_2,in0_3,in1_3,in2_3,in3_3,in0_4,in1_4,in2_4,in3_4,in0_5,in1_5,in2_5,in3_5,in0_6,in1_6,in2_6,in3_6,in0_7,in1_7,in2_7,in3_7,in0_8,in1_8,in2_8,in3_8 :STD_LOGIC;    
signal q1,q2,q3,q4,q5,q6,q7,q8 : STD_LOGIC;



begin

DFF1 : DFF port map(d1,q1,rst,clk);   
DFF2 : DFF port map(d2,q2,rst,clk);                                                                   DFF3 : DFF port map(d3,q3,rst,clk);  
DFF4 : DFF port map(d4,q4,rst,clk);  
DFF5 : DFF port map(d5,q5,rst,clk);                                                                 DFF6 : DFF port map(d6,q6,rst,clk);
DFF7 : DFF port map(d7,q7,rst,clk);
DFF8 : DFF port map(d8,q8,rst,clk);  

MUX1 : four_one_mux port map(in0_1,in1_1,in2_1,in3_1,sel(0),sel(1),y1);   
MUX2 : four_one_mux port map(in0_2,in1_2,in2_2,in3_2,sel(0),sel(1),y2);  
MUX3 : four_one_mux port map(in0_3,in1_3,in2_3,in3_3,sel(0),sel(1),y3);   
MUX4 : four_one_mux port map(in0_4,in1_4,in2_4,in3_4,sel(0),sel(1),y4);   
MUX5 : four_one_mux port map(in0_5,in1_5,in2_5,in3_5,sel(0),sel(1),y5);   
MUX6 : four_one_mux port map(in0_6,in1_6,in2_6,in3_6,sel(0),sel(1),y6);   
MUX7 : four_one_mux port map(in0_7,in1_7,in2_7,in3_7,sel(0),sel(1),y7);   
MUX8 : four_one_mux port map(in0_8,in1_8,in2_8,in3_8,sel(0),sel(1),y8);  

process(clk,sel)   
begin   

if(clk = '1' and clk'event) then   
if sel = "00" then   
d1 <= y1;   
d2 <= y2;   
d3 <= y3;   
d4 <= y4;   
d5 <= y5;   
d6 <= y6;   
d7 <= y7;   
d8 <= y8;  
end if;  

if( sel = "01") then   

in1_8 <= serial_in_rt_ip;--input to the mux   
--y8 is not getting updated with the input value!!!!.   
d8 <= y8;    
in1_7 <= q8;   
d7 <= y7;   
in1_6 <= q7;   
d6 <= y6;  
in1_5 <= q6;   
d5 <= y5;   
in1_4 <= q5;   
d4 <= y4;   
in1_3 <= q4;   
d3 <= y3;   
in1_2 <= q3;   
d2 <= y2;   
in1_1 <= q2;   
d1 <= y1;   
serial_out <= q1;   

end if;   

if( sel="10") then   
in2_1 <= serial_in_left_ip;   
d1 <= y1;   
in2_2 <= q1;   
d2 <= y2;   
in2_3 <= q2;   
d3 <= y3;   
in2_4 <= q3;   
d4 <= y4;   
in2_5 <= q4;   
d5 <= y5;   
in2_6 <=q5;  
d6 <= y6;   
in2_7 <= q6;   
d7 <= y7;   
in2_8 <= q7;   
d8 <= y8;   
serial_out <= q8;  
end if;  

if(sel ="11") then  

in3_1 <= parallel_ip(0);   
in3_2 <= parallel_ip(1);   
in3_3 <= parallel_ip(2);   
in3_4 <= parallel_ip(3);   
in3_5 <= parallel_ip(4);   
in3_6 <= parallel_ip(5);   
in3_7 <= parallel_ip(6);   
in3_8 <= parallel_ip(7); 

d1 <= y1;    
d2 <= y2;   
d3 <= y3;   
d4 <= y4;   
d5 <= y5;   
d6 <= y6;   
d7 <= y7;   
d8 <= y8;   


parallel_out(0) <= q1;   
parallel_out(1) <= q2;   
parallel_out(2) <= q3;   
parallel_out(3) <= q4;   
parallel_out(4) <= q5;   
parallel_out(5) <= q6;   
parallel_out(6) <= q7;   
parallel_out(7) <= q8;   

end if;  

end if;  

end process;  

end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your stated goal of coding a shift register using a mux and dff, you shouldn't be using a process in your shift register design at all.

You should be able to directly connect your 8 DFF and MUX components such that you get a shift register. Currently, you are creating additional (and redundant) MUXes and DFFs in your process.

My recommendation to get this working: draw a block diagram using 8 MUXes and 8 DFFs, then write the VHDL to describe your block diagram.

Comment: I tried passing serial_in_rt_ip directly to mux outside the clocked process, but still observing the same error!

Comment: @Santosh: Looking at your design more closely, you shouldn't need a process at all. Please see my revised answer.